# Django modelforms customization

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I'm using modelforms in my django-app and as I read in the documentation I can customize them by overriding the default field types or widgets. Does anyone know if I can do the customization by using django-crispy-forms in order to use bootstrap?

Comment: What do you mean by "the customization"? As there is even a [test](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/tests/forms.py) for a `ModelForm` I'd assume that crispy-forms doesn't care if it renders a standard `Form` or a `ModelForm`.

Comment: django-crispy-forms literally has a bootstrap theme, so yeah.. I think it'll work with bootstrap. Sheesh. Just *try it*. If you have problems then come here. Otherwise, don't waste everyone's time.

Comment: This is not my question. Of course django-crispy-forms will work with bootstrap. That's obvious. But what about MODELforms and not just simply forms?Will I be able to customize the template since they're being rendered differently from the classic forms? Sorry if my question is trivial but I'm facing a dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `cripsy-forms`, but by reading through the [documentation](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/), and looking at [an example](https://gist.github.com/1838193), it would appear that `cripsy-forms` simply augments django's built in forms to provide nicer rendering (by using helper model fields and template tags) so yes, you will still be able to customize your forms as you would